# Extract leaf cert and private key from CRT using openssl

Tags: openssl, certificate, pem

Hello I have a CRT file in PEM format that has the cert chain and private key in this order leaf > intermediate > root > Private Key and I am trying to separate them hopefully into two files. The first file containing the leaf cert and the second file with only the private key using Openssl.

I seem to remember reading how to do this somewhere but now I can not find it anywhere. I have tried these and other command is there a way to do this?

I have tried the following commands

```
openssl x509 -inform pem -in name.crt -pubkey > certificate_publickey.pem
```

openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile name.crt | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -text -noout> certificate_publickey.pem

Update I was able to pull and decode the key using

```
openssl rsa -in name.crt -out mumble-key.pem -passin pass:<redacted>
```

Now just need to figure out out to extract the leaf cert into a txt file or the cert chain with no key